# How to finish Recent open Activity when user come back in MainActivity?

Tags: android, back-button

**Understand Situation:>** I make Music Player (MediaPlayer) in SecondActiviy. When i play this and come back in Main Activity then song plays in MainActivity also.

So i want to know that- **"when user come back from SecondActivity to FirstActivity by click *Back Button of phone* then SecondActivity will finish.**

Comment: So you want to stop media player in MainActivity?

Comment: can you post what you've done so far? so we can understand what you're trying to achieve. you can override the `onBackPressed` method

Comment: @AnandJain i want to finish SecondActivity by BackButton. I want to do Second Activity finish, then MediaPlayer will automatic Stop.  (in simple words- i want to finish SecondActivity by backbutton then all thing in that Activity will be automatic finish)

Comment: @AnandJain  Can i Stop background process like mediaplayer by finish SecondActivity where mediaplayer exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution you are watching for is following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
           mediaPlayer.stop();
           mediaPlayer.release();
           mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    finish();
}
```

Comment: mediaPlayer is a situation. I want to finish that SecondActivity.class where i create MediaPlayer.  So suggest how to finish that SecondActivity.class . I think if  SecondActivity will finish(mean on run in background) then musicPlayer will be automatic stop.

Comment: Your Activity gets finished with `finish`, but referring to the Docs it is recommended to release the MediaPlayer from your resources. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer

Comment: i want to just  finish  SecondActivity completely so i try **@Override public void onBackPressed() { finish();}**  , but it not finish activity that mediaPlayer remain play in background in MainActivity.